# Are fight scenes in "Under control" sped up?

Tags: effects, under-control

I just watched [Jackie Chan's "Under control"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0184526/) (1999), and the fighting scenes are looking too quick. So, are fighting scenes really sped up?

I don't remember seeing anything similar before.

---

Actually, this weekend I watched a movie by Bud Spencer and Terrence Hill (do not remember the title), and some scenes were definitely sped up.

Comment: I found a link to the movie on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLdIc2B_9-M